# Best way to implement [user — subscriptions/subscribers] relation in database

Tags: swift, postgresql, orm, vapor

I am writing a server using Swift 4 + Vapor framework, Fluent ORM and PostgreSQL as a driver. I've got a User Model which should have subscribers and subscriptions (which are also User Models). I have two options here: 1. store arrays with unique ids of subscriptions/subscribers or 2. build a one-to-many User-User relation. Which one do you think is better and how can I impemplement it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing an array is not optimal. Querying your database to find all a User's subscribers will require parsing every User's subscriptions array and finding those which contain your target User's ID. A relation is a better idea.

Fluent uses the [Pivot](https://docs.vapor.codes/2.0/fluent/relations/#siblings) class to model many-to-many relations. Because it's a self-referencing relation, to avoid ID key conflicts you will probably find it easiest to create your own 'through' model.

```
import FluentProvider
import Vapor

final class Subscription: Model, PivotProtocol {

  typealias Left = User
  typealias Right = User

  var subscriberId: Identifier
  var subscribedId: Identifier

  init(
    subscriberId: Identifier,
    subscribedId: Identifier
  ) {
    self.subscriberId = subscriberId
    self.subscribedId = subscribedId
  }

  let storage = Storage()

  static let leftIdKey = "subscriber_id"
  static let rightIdKey = "subscribed_id"

  init(row: Row) throws {
    subscriberId = try row.get("subscriber_id")
    subscribedId = try row.get("subscribed_id")
  }

  func makeRow() throws -> Row {
    var row = Row()
    try row.set("subscriber_id", subscriberId)
    try row.set("subscribed_id", subscribedId)
    return row
  }

}

extension User {
  var subscribers: Siblings<User, User, Subscription> {
    return siblings(localIdKey: "subscriber_id", foreignIdKey: "subscribed_id")
  }
  var subscribed: Siblings<User, User, Subscription> {
    return siblings(localIdKey: "subscribed_id", foreignIdKey: "subscriber_id")
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a great and detailed answer! I think it is a good starting point ^‿^